# Maui Blazor hybrid, issue that the footer in home.razor is not positioned right at the bottom, it floats about 100px above the bottom

Tags: ios, blazor, maui

In Maui Blazor hybrid, I have the issue that the footer in home.razor is not positioned right at the bottom, it floats about 100px above the bottom. After opening another app and returning to the app, it is neatly positioned at the bottom.
I have this problem only at Apple Iphone, Android and Windows works fine.

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world 2024!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.


<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;width:100%; background:red;height:100px">
    Footer
</div>
```

[After first load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U27V.png)
[After app switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0eCj.png)

I removed all the default css and bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a [safe area](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/layout#Guides-and-safe-areas), which defines the area within a view that isn’t covered by a navigation bar, tab bar, toolbar, or other views a window or scene might provide.

In your MainPage.xaml,

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             ...
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True"
            >
```

Hope it helps!